# Joy UI - Dark mode in only one section of an app

Tags: reactjs, joy-ui

I am using MUI Joy UI, and enjoying it. My overall app is in light mode, however I want one section of the app (the sidebar) to use darker colours. I am trying to set only that section of the app to use dark mode, keeping the rest of the app in light mode.

I have a root CssVarsProvider defaulting to light mode working correctly. I have tried

- Adding a second CssVarsProvider wrapping the side bar, set to dark mode
- Setting a different modeStorageKey on the second CssVarsProvider
- Setting disableNestedContext on the second CssVarsProvider

These changes have not resulted in any noticeable difference to the app. I have tried clearing local storage.

I have found examples of doing this for Material UI but not for Joy UI.

How can I use dark mode in a section of a light mode app, or is there a better way to achieve the same outcome?

Update:

I found the following extra documentation but I haven't got it to work yet

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/pull/35277

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to toggle between light/dark in a nested provider. Using a nested providers works nicely, but when using `useColorScheme` it changes the top level provider's mode as well. I'd like it to only apply to the nested provider.

Comment: Thanks @judehall, it sounds like you have got further than me if you have nested CssVarsProviders working. When I nest them the inner CssVarsProvider seems to be ignored. Any chance you could give me some pointers?

Comment: @judehall I have added an answer below. I suspect you may be able to use it for your scenario by making the theme property on the child CssVarsProvider conditional on some of your own state. Instead of using useColorScheme

Comment: see solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77558536/648580

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to do what I want. I suspect it is not the best way, but perhaps it might be useful to someone.

I have a root CssVarsProvider as usual

```
<CssVarsProvider>
    <CssBaseline />
    <App />
</CssVarsProvider>
```

Then in my sidebar component somewhere within my App, I have something like

```
import { CssVarsProvider, extendTheme } from "@mui/joy";

const baseTheme = extendTheme();

const darkOnlyTheme = extendTheme({
    cssVarPrefix: "sidebar_",
    colorSchemes: {
        light: baseTheme.colorSchemes.dark,
        dark: baseTheme.colorSchemes.dark,
    },
});

export default function Sidebar() {
    return (
        <CssVarsProvider theme={darkOnlyTheme}>
            {/* My sidebar layout here... */}
        </CssVarsProvider>
    );
}
```